# Cloning node and appending to xml

Tags: javascript, xml

I need some javascript (not JQuery etc) codes to copy a clone node and insert it just next 
to the copied node. For eg.

```
<a>
    <b>
        <ab></ab>
        <bc></bc>
    </b>
</a>
```

Now after copying the `<b>` node from the source xml and appending it as next sibling,

```
    <a>
        <b>
            <ab></ab>
            <bc></bc>
        </b>
        <!-- this is the copied node that will be appended. -->
        <b>
            <ab></ab>
            <bc></bc>
        </b>
        <!-- copied node ends here. -->
    </a>
```

I shall be grateful If some body show me some code example, which is supported in atleast Mozilla2 and IE5+.
The CloneNode method doesnot works properly in many primitive version of major browsers. CloneNode is however supported in All IE browsers. So cloneNode method will not be a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are getting the required node by ID, here's how you can clone an existing node and append the clone as a sibling node:

```
var node = document.getElementById("toBeCloned");
var parentNode = node.parentNode;
alert(parentNode.outerHTML);
var clonedNode = node.cloneNode(true);
clonedNode.removeAttribute("id");
parentNode.appendChild(clonedNode);
alert(parentNode.outerHTML);
```

The `alerts` will show what the XML looked before and after the insertion.

This code will work with Mozilla and any reasonable version of IE. I cannot guarantee IE5 to IE7 support because I don't have access to those browsers.

Comment: Thanks for writing the codes for me Abbas. But I mentioned that the cloneNode method doesnot works properly in most of the primitive version of the old browsers. I need something other then cloneNode method because my program is targetted with the old browsers itself.

Comment: In that case, you need to use createElement. However, the problem with that approach will be that you will have to create all the child nodes within a given node by yourself. This means recursively going through the node, getting the names of child nodes, calling the createElement method and append new nodes to the parent node.